# Check if Private browsing menuitem is checked in safari applescript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I want to disable the private browsing using apple script

before i run the disable code i want to make sure **PrivateMode** is **enabled**

for disabling i use following apple script

```
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Safari"
    click menu item "Private Browsing" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
end tell
end tell
```

The problem is that if i run this script and private browsing is not activated it will activate the private mode.

So i want the check to detect if private mode is enabled .So only then i will call the above apple script

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "**AXMenuItemMarkChar**" attribute to get the checked of a menu item.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        tell menu item "Private Browsing" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            if value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" is "✓" then click -- disabling
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Updated:

To not open an application (AppleScript applet or droplet) to the foreground : Use this script to add the property `LSBackgroundOnly` in the **Info.plist** of the bundle (the applet).

```
set tApp to choose file with prompt "Select your application (applet AppleScript)"
set tPlist to quoted form of ((POSIX path of tApp) & "Contents/Info")
do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write " & tPlist & " LSBackgroundOnly -bool TRUE"
do shell script "/usr/bin/defaults write " & tPlist & " LSUIElement -bool TRUE"
```

Comment: one quick question: whenever the script is run by app . app comes to foreground .i.e when i am browsing on safari and this script is run by my app safari goes to background and app comes foreground. I dont want my app to come foreground

Comment: this is not my issue. i dont want app to run background . i am calling this script from my app timer every 15 seconds .when i am browsing in safari and the script is called my app comes in front so i need to go back to safari by clicking on safari icon every time

Comment: Why not try it, the only change it makes is that the application is not visible, the application will quit and opens normally but it don't comes to the foreground.

Or save the script as *script* format, use the `load script` and the `run script` command to launch the script file.

Answer (score 1):

**Fun fact:**
Running Safari on a German system, the menu item title "Private Browsing …" switches to "Private Browsing" *(without the three points)*. It is impossible to switch private browsing on and off with the same handler

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        try
            -- turn Private Browsing on
            click menu item "Privates Surfen …" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            -- turn Private Browsing off
            click menu item "Privates Surfen" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
        end try
    end tell
end tell
```

I don't have an English system here, maybe there is such title switch on your system, too?

Michael / Hamburg